# In D&D 5e is there a spell or ability that mimics the D&D 2e Priest spell Combine?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, adnd-2e

In 2nd Ed there was a 1st LV spell called [Combine](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Combine).
It allowed the caster to combine forces with other casters to increase the effective level of his Turning ability as well as increased his caster level for spells.

Is there a spell or ability in 5e that does something similar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### There is no such feature in *5th Edition*.

I can't properly *prove* this to you. But you can read through all of the class and subclass features of the 5e Cleric [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric) and you will not find anything like this.

Additionally, there are no feats or magic items that interact with the cleric's *turn undead* class feature in the way you are asking about.

Further, I am certain there are no abilities in 5e that allow you to temporarily increase your level or treat your level as though it was increased temporarily. Again, there is no way to prove this to you other than to say "go read all the source books, and note that no such feature exists."

Comment: I have read everything and couldn't find it either.  I asked for verification.  I had hope that I missed something.